# What is the difference between ‘ swam on’ and ‘swam’?

Tags: word-usage

> After it had passed, they swam on as quickly as they could because they knew that the boat would soon return.

Can I replace ‘swam on’ with ‘swam’? What is the difference between ‘swam on’ and ‘swam’?

Answer (score 2):

To *[verb] on* means **to continue to [verb]**, generally in the same manner or direction as you were before.<sup>1</sup>

Thus, to *swim on* means to keep on swimming, probably in the same direction as they were before. In this case, it indicates that they didn't stop (or remain stopped), or turn back or divert their course. That conveys additional meaning that would not be there if it were just *swam* without *on*.

Note, however, that *on* can also be a preposition for an adverbial phrase. "I walked on the path" is not *walk on*, but *walk* with an adverbial of location.

---

<sup>1</sup>: There are exceptions, such as *carry on* which is really a phrasal verb that connotes a more general meaning along the lines of the above without being specific about what is to be continued.

Comment: carry on functions just like swam on here, if you think about it.

Comment: @Lambie I think **carry on** is different with **draw on**, for we can omit **on** of **draw on**, but we can't omit **on** of **carry on**. Am I right?

Comment: @Y.zeng, on in these phrases means: to continue to do **an action**.

Comment: @Lambie So, can I omit **on** in **carry on**?

Comment: @Y.zeng No, then you change the meaning. The verb draw can mean many things and it is most UNLIKELY you will find draw on, meaning: to continue to draw, like on paper with a pencil. Here is a famous British song sung during WWII: And the Band Played On: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0hlzE4MaZQ played on there means: continued to play

Comment: How about omitting **on** in **carry on**?